# Pointing menu in semantic-ui breackdown in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, menu, semantic-ui

i started learn to codding with semantig-ui framework but in first step i see different behavior in chrome
pointing menu left element (such as searchbox) breakdown in chrome , but other browser is correct view

this image for pointing menu in chrome(ver 43.0)
[IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/nmzwc0.jpg[/IMG]

this image for pointing menu in firefox
[IMG]http://i60.tinypic.com/x57fxg.jpg[/IMG]

sorry for poor english

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem , placing a jquery with web address and solved the problem

i first palce local address(in the root of project) for jquery

so , tnx